# How to merge only chosen columns of right frame?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

How to join only column 'd'? And avoid of joining 'c' as well. It's deliberate that names of key-columns are different ('a' and 'c', accordingly).

t1

```
    a   b
0   5   2
1   3   4
2   1   6
```

t2

```
    c   d
0   1   20
1   3   40
2   5   60
```

result

```
**t1.merge(t2, left_on='a', right_on='c')**
    a   b   c   d
0   5   2   5   60
1   3   4   3   40
2   1   6   1   20
```

DESIRED RESULT IS:

```
    a   b   d
0   5   2   60
1   3   4   40
2   1   6   20
```

Comment: Don't post dataframes as images, post them as text

Comment: Also can you clarify your desired output?

Comment: desired result should incorporate only 'a', 'b' and 'd' columns. And not the 'c' column. So I want to join only 'd' column from t2-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the differently labeled keys from being duplicated, you can just rename them in the merge:

```
t1.merge(t2.rename(columns={'c': 'a'}), on='a')
   a  b   d
0  5  2  60
1  3  4  40
2  1  6  20
```

Alternatively, in the case of just bringing a single column without duplicated keys, you could always just `map`

```
t1['d'] = t1.a.map(t2.set_index('c').d)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only add the **`d`** column to the first Dataframe, just concat **`d`**:

```
pd.concat([t1, t2.d], 1)

   a  b   d
0  5  2  20
1  3  4  40
2  1  6  60
```

Or using **`join`**:

```
t1.join(t2.d)

   a  b   d
0  5  2  20
1  3  4  40
2  1  6  60
```

If you have a subset of columns from the second DataFrame you want to add:

```
t1.join(t2[cols])
```

Or:

```
pd.concat([t1, t2[cols]])
```